# Using pdb, how can I run a program and pause where reaching an error?

Tags: python, pdb

Using `python` interpreter and/or `pdb`, can we run a program and pause whenever reaching an error, so that I can examine all the frames of the call stack of the program at the time of crashing?

When I run a program directly inside `python` interpreter, when reaching an error, it tells where the line of code it happens, but it seems return to the topmost frame, and I can't examine the frame where the error actually happens. E.g.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test.py", line 194, in <module>
    addlevel(root_toc, 0)
  File "test.py", line 191, in addlevel
    addlevel(child, root_level+1)
  File "test.py", line 188, in addlevel
    root.value.append(root_level)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
>>> root_level
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'root_level' is not defined
```

The error happens at the lowest frame, and I can't examine the value of `root_level` at that frame. Is it because it returns to the topmost frame after the error happens? How can examine the lowest frame?

THanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run pdb as a module, passing the script you want to debug. It will break on abnormal exits. (This is mentioned early in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html).)

```
python -m pdb my_script.py
```

If you're in the interpreter, you can use [`pdb.pm()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html#pdb.pm) to debug the last traceback.

---

Or, use the IPython interpreter. Typing [`debug`](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.magics.execution.html?highlight=debug#IPython.core.magics.execution.ExecutionMagics.debug) after an uncaught exception will enter a pdb session for the last traceback, similar to `pm()`.